# How can I use curl with ::1 for ipv6 based loopback?

Tags: ipv6, localhost, curl, loopback

I tried a few ways but they seem to be confusing curl.

```
root@testt:~# curl localhost:8080
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

<p>Boom Bam Splat</p>
root@testt:~# curl ::1:8080
curl: (3) IPv6 numerical address used in URL without brackets
root@testt:~# curl [::1]:8080
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the answers earlier! I was genuinely hard pressed for which to accept since they were both so concise and whatnot, though I chose the other since that user is just starting out compared to you and answered first. Regardless, just using the - g option was sufficient.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Update**: As of December 28, 2022 and at least Curl version 7.68.0 one can simply use Curl like this, without the `-g` flag, and it works fine:

```
curl -6 "http://[::1]:8080/"
```

Older answer below for reference.

---

Looking at the suggestions — and breakdown of common errors [in this blog post](http://vicendominguez.blogspot.com/2014/03/curl-ipv6-common-errors-using-direct-ip.html) — perhaps you should try this.

```
curl -g -6 "http://[::1]:8080/"
```

The `-g` seems to be the magical key to get this working. As explained on the [`curl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) man page:

> This option switches off the "URL globbing parser". When you set this option, you can specify URLs that contain the letters {}[] without having them being interpreted by curl itself. Note that these letters are not normal legal URL contents but they should be encoded according to the URI standard.

And the `-6` means to use IPv6 only:

> If libcurl is capable of resolving an address to multiple IP versions (which it is if it is IPv6-capable), this option tells libcurl to resolve names to IPv6 addresses only.

But reading that functionality description, it seems like `-6` is not really needed for a pure IPv6 address; only if one is using `curl` on a hostname that has an IPv4 and IPv6 address connected to it so it would prefer the IPv6. Just something to note.

Comment: I don't seem to need the `-g` flag.   Just `-6` is enough for me; this with curl 7.85

Comment: @jeffmcc Thanks for the comment! just tested using this with Curl 7.68.0 in macOS 13 (Ventura) and using just -6 works 100% fine for me as well. Will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 11):

From "curl --manual", I found this:

```
curl -g "http://[2001:1890:1112:1::20]/"
```

or

```
curl "http://[2001:1890:1112:1::20]/"
```

So, for the address you're asking about, try:

```
curl -g "http://[::1]:8080/"
```

However, you may want to run:

```
curl -V
```

and see if IPv6 shows up on the line that says "Features" (the third line, not counting extra lines from word wrapping).  I found my version didn't.  [cURL download page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) has various links for operating systems, including [curl 7.41.0 download site](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.41.0) (which is currently the latest version) for Microsoft Windows.  That page has multiple executables (available for Microsoft Windows); the first one I found did not support IPv6.  But the two described as "ipv6-sspi-spnego-winssl" (one for x86 and one for x64) did : curl -V did show IPv6.  So be careful about which package you download.